# Import .js file at runtime in NestJs

Tags: nestjs

I need help.
I'm trying to dynamically load a js file like this:

```
async read() {
    const base = this.configService.get('BASE_PATH');
    const folder = this.configService.get('MIGRATIONS_DIR');
    const folderPath = path.join(base, folder);

    const files = await fs.readdir('migrations');

    const promises = files.map(async file => {
      const modPath = path.join(folderPath, file);
      let mod;

      try {
        mod = (await import(modPath));
      } catch (e) {
        throw e;
      }

      return { name: file, run: mod.run };
    });

    const migrations = await Promise.all(promises);
    console.log('... ', migrations);
  }
```

The error says:

```
/home/jose/WORK/Rental/REAL/APPS/management/dist/apps/ns-backend/webpack:/src/infrastructure/migrations/service/ sync:2
        var e = new Error("Cannot find module '" + req + "'");
^
Error: Cannot find module '/home/jose/WORK/Rental/REAL/APPS/management/migrations/1.update-db.js'
    at webpackEmptyContext (/home/jose/WORK/Rental/REAL/APPS/management/dist/apps/ns-backend/webpack:/src/infrastructure/migrations/service/ sync:2:1)
    at /home/jose/WORK/Rental/REAL/APPS/management/dist/apps/ns-backend/webpack:/src/infrastructure/migrations/service/migration.service.ts:25:36
```

If I try to put the location of the manual file, it works.
I imagined that it had to do with webpack, but I'm copying the folder with the plugin and it still doesn't work.

```
const { composePlugins, withNx } = require('@nx/webpack');
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

// Nx plugins for webpack.
module.exports = composePlugins(withNx(), (config) => {
  // Update the webpack config as needed here.
  // e.g. `config.plugins.push(new MyPlugin())`
  config.plugins.push(new CopyPlugin({
    patterns: [
      { from: '../../migrations', to: 'migrations' },
    ]
  }));

  return config;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `require` instead of `import`

```js
 try {
      // Use require instead of import for dynamic loading
      mod = require(modPath);
 } catch (e) {
      throw e;
 }

    return { name: file, run: mod.run };
  });

  const migrations = await Promise.all(promises);
  console.log('... ', migrations);
}
```

> One of the major differences between require() and import() is that require() can be called from anywhere inside the program whereas import() cannot be called conditionally, it always runs at the beginning of the file.

[require-vs-import](https://flexiple.com/javascript/javascript-require-vs-import/)